# Increased vandalism

Tags: support

I've noticed spam-bots and anonymous presumably bored people vandalizing answers lately. Some are "kind" enough to leave their email in the comment field - though I'm not sure the email belong to them.

Do we have a watchlist we can submit these emails to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a watch list per se, but if you mark the comment as SPAM, you'll teach our SPAM bot that this user (and associated IP-addresses) are spamming the site. Soon enough, they will not be able to post anything.

Comment: What about anonymous user vandalism edits? I know we can Reject the edit and mark it as Spam, but the edit was made by an anonymous user - how can we prevent that without disallowing anonymous edits?

Comment: @DanielZiga The SPAM flag also marks the IP-address. So if some anonymous user keeps editing and get SPAM flags, that IP will be blacklisted for anonymous users.

Comment: Cool. Good to know :)